# Is it possible to store a variable with a variable in a variable?

Tags: php, sql, variables, nested, store

I'm facing an interesting problem here. I have a piece of code where I'd like to send some data from different arrays to my database. The problem is that I have a lot of code duplication, so I was trying to make a function out of it. An example:

```
$i = "0";
$education = $user['education'][$i]['school']['name'];
while ($education != null){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO educations VALUES(
    {$user['id']},
    '{$user['education'][$i]['school']['name']}'
  )");
  }
  $i++;
  $education = $user['education'][$i]['school']['name'];
}
```

And I'd like it to work like this:

```
$i = "0";
$item = $user['education'][$i]['school']['name'];
$table = 'educations'
$current = $item;
while ($current != 'EOL'){
  if ($current != null){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} VALUES(
    {$user['id']},
    '{$item}'
  )");
  }
  $i++;
  $current = $item;
}
```

The thing I'm trying to do is to save the variable variable `$user['education'][$i]['school']['name']` in `$item` in such a way that, whenever I store `$item` in another variable, it inserts the value of `$i` again. I don't know if this is even possible, but it's something interesting to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For variables names, you can use something like ${'myvariable_'.$i}, which will output $myvariable_0, _1, ...
For array, I don't think it works (can you try it please?), else you should use a function like that:

```
function getNthSchoolName($n) {
    global $user;
    return $user[''][$n]['schoool']['name'];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with arrays, the quotation of the array variables generates an error and escaping the quotes (obviously) doesn't return the right object. I will use your function though, thanks!